# Subselect grouped associative array in Groovy

Tags: groovy

For a Groovy associative array grouped by an item, how can I select a subset within each group?

In the following how would I select 2 items for each `id`?

```
assocarray = [ ["id":1, "num":1], ["id":1, "num":2], 
    ["id":1, "num":3], ["id":1, "num":4], ["id":1, "num":5], 
    ["id":2, "num":1], ["id":2, "num":2], ["id":2, "num":3], 
    ["id":2, "num":4], ["id":2, "num":5]]
    .groupBy {it.id}
```

Comment: Expected output please?

Comment: Which expected result do you wish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take(n)` to take up to `n` elements from a collection.  E.g.

```
def data = [[id:1, num:1], [id:1, num:2], [id:1, num:3], [id:1, num:4], [id:1, num:5], [id:2, num:1], [id:2, num:2], [id:2, num:3], [id:2, num:4], [id:2, num:5]]

// XXX take(2) from the values
println data.groupBy{it.id}.collectEntries{[it.key, it.value.take(2)]}
// => [1:[[id:1, num:1], [id:1, num:2]], 2:[[id:2, num:1], [id:2, num:2]]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I looking for, thanks. I'm new to Groovy syntax, and couldn't figure how to "Google it out".